# Memory leak in my app? Is garbage collection in code a good practice?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, garbage-collection

I am developing a Spring web application with Spring 3.1 + Jetty 8.1.2 + Eclipse (Juno).

I notice that when the app runs, memory is consumed quickly with each run and does not come down, even after I stop running it.

So, based on my research, I inserted

jlibs.core.lang.RuntimeUtil.gc();

at the end of my code processing user requests. This line of code stops memory usage from going up and memory usage is always low.

My question:

1. Do you feel that my app has any memory leak?
2. Is running garbage collection in code a good practice? What is the best practice (overall design or in case of Spring) in garbage collection?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The code would be cracking.

Comment: There is very little point in ever calling `System.gc()` as the garbage collection will do that when it needs to. If the memory usage is not reaching the limits of `Xmx` then there is no reason for the garbage collector to concern itself.

Comment: If executing gc helps, I don't think there's a memory leak. How exactly do you notice the memory getting consumed?

Comment: @flup, for the memory usage, I watch it in Windows Task Manager. I use a Windows machine.

Comment: @bmorris591, I recall that calling gc should not be my app's job. It should be Java's job. Is the high memory usage caused by my development environemnt (Spring 3.1 + Jetty 8.1.2 + Eclipse (Juno))?

Comment: Yeah, all those dependencies would mean a load of Objects being created.

Comment: There are a few environments (Android being one) where explicitly calling GC is required to manage heap (because running GC triggers the cleanup of some non-Java heap storage), but for pure Java applications it's never necessary and rarely productive.

Comment: @curious1 The Windows Task Manager is not the right place to watch. You only see what's happening on the outside, but Java does not usually hand back memory to the OS. Use JVisualVM or JConsole instead. They show how much of the allocated memory is actually in use.

Comment: HotLicks and flup, thanks so much for your input!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your application can claim back the memory then it is certainly not a memory leak. No reason to worry about the memory usage.

There is very little point in ever calling `System.gc()` as the garbage collection will do that when it needs to. If the memory usage is not reaching the limits of `Xmx` then there is no reason for the garbage collector to concern itself.

Unless your getting `OutOfMemoryError` don't concern yourself with RAM usage. If you want to use less RAM then reduce the amount allocated to the JVM - reduce `Xmx`.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your questions:

1. Your application may still consume resources that are not relevant and their memory consumption is not released (probably on the HEAP). In this case Running GC is a waste of time since your app still referencing these resources/objects.
2. It is a known fact that the virtual machine calls GC automatically as needed for recycling purposes, so the answer is no, calling GC will not solve your problem.

I do suggest working with a Java Profiler to see where do you have high consumption of un-released memory and continue from there.

In addition, you can use some of the -X JVM arguments to increase memory, but again if you suspect you have a "memory leak" this is only a temporary solution.